# Django error: No module named _mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

I am migrating my app on prod mariadb database from default django's sqlitedb. There are python3.3 + centos 7 + django 1.8 + apache envirounment.
On sqlite everything is working fine but after there migration i have such error after apache restarting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/mainproject/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
  application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql
```

I have installed mysqlclient as it said here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers.
Than i have did manage.py syncdb and it had finished successfully. I have checked database structure and it is ok - all data had migrated.
But there is still such error on my app start.

The Solution is: to use non-official libs https://github.com/nakagami/django-cymysql/ It is easy to install and configure with django:

```
$ pip install cymysql
$ pip install django-cymysql
```

Than just add this engine to django's settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql_cymysql',
    'NAME': 'some_what_database',
    'HOST': ...,
    'USER': ...,
    'PASSWORD': ...,
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure that `libmysqlclient-dev` and `python3-dev` are installed?

Comment: Wtower, as i now this libs are for debian/ubuntu. I have find the solution -added to question's body.

Answer (score 1):

Try this; this solved my issue

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: MySQL-python is not supporting Python3 :(
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, I had to add `mysqlclient` to requirements, `MySQL-python` doesn't support Python3.